# SQL Server : when to use collation and nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, collation, varchar, multilingual, nvarchar

Currently my column datatype is `varchar` in my SQL Server table.

I want to store both English and Chinese characters in my column.

What steps do I have to follow to use collation, or do I have to change the datatype to `NVARCHAR` and insert with `N'` as unicode?

If I have to use collation what collation I should use.

Please help me in this

Comment: Use separate columns for english and chinese data, with proper collations, the sorting rules are different. Have two cols if you know there will ever be only these two languages, or a separate table with three cols - pointer to main data, ISO language id, and the value itself - if more than two languages might be needed.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing two concepts:

- data type and encoding

`VARCHAR` stores your data in chunks of 8 bit. The total of 256 different values is just not enough to address each and any character out there. UTF-8 , which is 1-byte-storage too, uses a trick for this: Basic characters are one chunk. But sometimes there is one special chunk telling the engine, that this character has to be interpreted as a two-byte character. If you get in touch with languages with a very differing char-set you'll find even characters which need three  or four bytes to encode one single character.

`VARCHAR` uses another trick: The collation adds a codepage to interpret the values. In most cases, the lower half is more or less "plain latin", while the upper half adds special characters for a given language. The count of special characters is **very** limited! That means, that the same value in `VARCHAR` will give different result looking at it through different collations.

`NVARCHAR` stores each character as UCS-2 (which is *almost the same* as UTF-16 - 2-byte-storage). This allows one single encoding for all characters, no tricks needed (well, there are some emojis...).

- Collation

The main purpose of a collation is used for sorting and string comparisons. It is used when you deal with string values in `WHERE`, within `JOIN`s or in indexes and for sorting of any kind.

As said above, it will add a codepage to interpret values, which is very important in the 1-byte-world.

SQL Server has a default collation which is used with new databases and - **very important!** - within your temp table.

It is allowed to define a different default collation on database level, but this can lead to severe problems, if you run queries against the temp table where the collation is not the same.

You are allowed to define the collation on column level too.

And you are allowed to define the collation even within your statements for each column separately. This is the highest grade of control but means a lot of typing and very *hard-to-read* code...

**Most imporant for you:**

If you want to store English and Chinese in one column you **must** use `NVARCHAR`. There is no *fitting-to-everything* collation, this you must try. And you **mus** add a leading `N` to any string literal (`N'your text'`).

You might store your strings in a side table with proper configuration and bind it within your queries...

### UPDATE: ad *proper configuration*:

You should use different columns for English and Chinese strings. Or even one separate side table for each language... This allows you to set the best collation for each column/language separately. And it makes it easy to add new languages in a multi-language environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store Far Eastern alphabets (Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc.) or Cyrillic, or Arab or Hebrew, then yes, you **must use** `nvarchar`.

And if you define a **string literal** in a SQL script that contains Unicode characters, then yes you **must use** the `N'....'` string prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please then we have to use sql server collation.

Comment: @MohammedZameerudeen Collation is for sorting and comparison.